# opennms Logging statements

Tags: logging, opennms

I am trying to log the logger statements to a file , when i run `opennms`.

Imagine a class named `AgentModifier`

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AgentModifier.class);

LOG.debug("I am inside method")
```

May I know where this string `I am inside method` will be printed. 
I tried doing some modifications in `log4j2.xml` file `/usr/share/opennms/etc` folder, but no improvements.

Could someone give me the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, all the log files of opennms are placed in `/opennms/logs` directory. If you are lucky, you should found the log.debug statements in `/opennms/logs/webapp/jetty.log` or in `/opennms/logs/daemon/output.log` file.